# CSS: shift div upward by half of its height?

Tags: html, css, margin

In CSS, I want to shift a div upward by half of its height, where its height isn't specified explicitly; it's based on the size of its contents. This could be with either `top` or `margin-top`. Does anyone know how to do this? If I just do `margin-top: 50%` I know that 50% will be 50% of the parent's width, rather than 50% of the div's height.

Answer (score 5):

You may try [`transform: translateY(-50%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY())

While assigning percentage units for translation, the distance is calculated by the corresponding axis, so `translateY(-50%)` is calculated based on it's height.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```